# Loop in Mysql using IF

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to ask you if is possible a loop in the SELECT in MYSQL:

```
"SELECT IF(5<field_number<15, 10, 
       (IF(15=<field_number<25, 20,
       (IF(25=<field_number<35, 30
        ...
       (IF(15=<field_number<225, 220) AS id_detail"
```

I need to compare twenty-two times. I was wondering if is possible to have a loop to increase the number initial and final in 10 and the true number in 10.

I was looking for some light on this but without success.

Thank you.

Comment: Loops are often a bad alternative when working with set based relational data. What is it you want to accomplish? Maybe there's a better way.

Comment: SQL doesn't know loops. There may be an alternative solution, but I'm not sure what exactly you need. The code in the question doesn't provide much clarity, since I think it doesn't work, or at least it probably doesn't work as you expect it it.

Comment: `FLOOR((field_number + 5) / 10) * 10`?

Comment: @GolezTrol actually it does check my answer.

Comment: @Mellamokb solution is really good. Check it.

Comment: I am using the IF statement IF(condition, true, false). I need to check it 22 times, but I would like to know if is possible with less code in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible when you create procedure

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/loop.html

On above link you will find examples of how to do it.

**Notice:**

In MySQL you have BETWEEN keyword you can use `15=<field_number<25` as `field_number BETWEEN 15 AND 25`

**Edit:**

@mellamokb solution with `SELECT (FLOOR((field_number + 5) / 10) * 10) as id_detail"` is really good by using it you will avoid using loops which is better approach.

Comment: Be careful with `BETWEEN` as it's inclusive on both ends, so `X <= Y <= Z` not `X <= Y < Z`.

Comment: I am using BETWEEN. Was the only way reasonable to reach my goal. Thank you.